# Clientside payment solution in React (no server)?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, payment

Do you know of any payment solution for React that don't require any backend? I've tried implementing Noodlio as it said that it would work for React. I could not find any projects using react and Noodlio and I didn't get it to work.

So: 
has anyone gotten Noodlio to work with React and are willing to tell me how?

Or are there any other payment solution that doesn't need a server?

Comment: I think it's dangerous to put such a logic in client side code

Comment: Agreed with the previous comment. You could setup a [minimal Stripe server](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payments are Exactly Transferring Money Or Giving Credit from One Client to Another.

Credit Amount Have to be save in some place.

Client-side is not a good field for this work because the receiver should trust the sender and sender always could get offline and get unreliable ....

so there need for an back-end which has to be:

- always accessible (online)
- trust able by a wide range of people

but this criteria can be made via 2 approaches:

- centralized : which needs a server which perform payment action and client would communicate with APIs.
- decentralized : client sending payments to miners to approve. (in this case there is no need for you to implement backend)

The Most Security issue that concerns client is how to avoid account hijacking:

- in centralized : client should transfer sensitive data securely and saving no tokens/ password in client system.
- in decentralized: client shouldn't save any private key or backup phrases in client side. every other aspects are secure via blockchain back-end.

> for a successful only **Client Implementation** Payment Solution, i
> recommend you to use Cryptocurrency blockchains as a backend.